# Unknotting a compact manifold in the PL setting

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, manifolds

The general position theorem asserts that any $M$ $m$-manifold unknots in $R^n$ provided $n\geq 2m+2$. The general position theorem assumes a smooth setting. Is unknotting still hold in the PL setting? what is the lower bound on n in that case? what is the argument for unknotting a general $m$-manifold (compact, closed, not necessarily connected ) in the PL setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if two PL-embeddings $f,g:M^k\hookrightarrow N^n$ of a compact $PL$ manifold of dimension $k$ are homotopic and $n\ge 2k+2$, then they are PL-isotopic.

This is Corollary 5.9 in

*Rourke, C. P.; Sanderson, B. J.*, Introduction to piecewise-linear topology, Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete. Band 69. Berlin-Heidelberg-New York: Springer-Verlag. VIII,123 p. with 58 fig. Cloth DM 42.00; $ 13.40 (1972). [ZBL0254.57010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0254.57010)

and a strengthened version is Theorem 4.1.1 in

*Daverman, Robert J.; Venema, Gerard A.*, Embeddings in manifolds, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 106. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-0-8218-3697-2/hbk). xvii, 468 p. (2009). [ZBL1209.57002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1209.57002).

Comment: Can corollary 5.9 be generalized to: if two PL-embeddings $f,g : M_1^k1 \sqcup M_2^{k2} \longrightarrow N^n$  are homotopic and $n\geq k_1+ k_2+2$ then they are PL-isotopic ? (here $M_i^{k_i}$ is a compact PL $k_i$ manifold  )

Comment: @Steve: I would say no. Note that the dimension of the disjoint union is $\operatorname{max}\{k_1,k_2\}$, and in general $k_1+k_2<2\operatorname{max}\{k_1,k_2\}$. In particular if $M^1=S^1$ and $M_2=\varnothing$ (regarded as a $0$-manifold, say) then with $N=S^3$ you get classical knot theory.

Comment: thank you. So the result holds with $n\geq max\{k_1,k_2\}+2$. Just to clarify, by PL-isotopic, do you mean PL-ambient isotopic? or something else ?

Comment: @Steve: I think you need a factor of 2 in front of the max. And I mean whatever is stated in those textbooks, I think it's ambient PL-isotopy.

Comment: Sure, dropping the 2 was a typo. thanks again!